# How to delete an object from an array in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

MongoDB collection/doc :

```
    {
      _id:something,
      name:something,
      todos: [
          {key:1234},
          {key:5678}
      ]
    }
```

I want to delete the object with key:5678 using mongoose query. I did something like this but It's not deleting the object at all and returning the User with unchanged todos array.

Node Route:

```
    router.post('/:action', async (req, res) => {
        try {
            if (req.params.action == "delete") {
                const pullTodo = { $pull: { todos: { key: 5678 } } }
                const todo = await User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id:req.body.id} },pullTodo)
                if (todo) {
                    res.json({ msg: "Todo Deleted", data: todo });
                }
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
```

I have allso tried findByIdAndUpdate(),update() methods but none of them deleting the object from the array. Getting User as a result without deleting the object from the array.

Comment: "it's not working" is an opinion, not a problem statement. _What happened_ that makde you conclude it's not working? Were there errors? (if so, show the error). What does the log show happening? (Show parts of the log relevant to your calls). Are you even querying the right database at all? (show the [mcve] that demonstrates you've at least got the basics covered). Effectively: remember to read the policy article on [how  to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) and update your post as best as you can accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It is working, but you forgot give an configuration to the function call of `Model.findByIdAndUpdate`..

```js
const todo = await User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id:req.body.id} },pullTodo, {new: true});
// if {new: true} is enabled, then it will give the latest & updated document from the
// result of the query. By default it gives the previous document.
```

Do some, research first. This isn't a type of question that should be asked. It's already been answered several times in stackoverflow.

Comment: I'v already gone through a lot of question here that's why I asked. Coming to your point, You must have skipped the line "Obejct is not being deleted by the query" .I don't care what doc old/new returns. My first motto is to delete the object from the array bro.

Comment: Looks like you have confusion about this. But mongoose actually deletes the Object containing `{key: 5678}`, but instead of returning the new Document, it returns the previous document & that's why it seems to be not deleted. Try making the query without setting `{new:true}` & check the Database by MongoShell/Compass/Atlas & you will see that is deleted but the previous doc is returned.

Comment: I run the code and checked Mongodb but still the todos array is unchanged. Mongoose is not deleting the obj at mongodb. I'v applied push method in another route which is working like a charm. Issue is with '$pull' only

Comment: Then something wrong is going on other part of your code. This should have worked fine. Could you please add the error logs of that current operation. Also try `console.log(todo)` for watching what is going on

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Model.findOneAndRemove()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndRemove) instead. It also makes only one call to the database.

Example: `User.findOneAndRemove({'todos':{'$elemMatch':{key}});`

Comment: Unfortunately, It's doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

can you please re-visit your JSON like below and see if this design works for you.

```
> db.test6.find()
{ "_id" : "mallik", "name" : "mallik-name", "todos1" : { "key1" : [ 1234, 5678 ] } }
> db.test6.update({},{$pull:{"todos1.key1":5678}},{multi:true});
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
> db.test6.find()
{ "_id" : "mallik", "name" : "mallik-name", "todos1" : { "key1" : [ 1234 ] } }
>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was adding a key property to every "Todo" using "mongoose.Types.ObjectId()" and I was querying with id string like : "5f439....." which was the problem. So I used:

```
1st Step: MongoId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
2nd Step: const key = MongoId (**<actual id here>**);
```